# Can't find ruby element with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, nested-forms

I've been trying since yesterday to find a nested_form link_to_add button using selenium. When I copy its XPATH from chrome and paste it into the script:

```
element = browser.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@id='tabpage_1']/a")
```

I get the following error when running selenium:

```
<main>': undefined method `*' for //:Regexp (NoMethodError)
```

If you know of any other way detect such a element it would be very appreciated. This is the elements HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add_nested_fields" data-association="levels">Add Level</a>
```

Comment: That's not valid ruby, because you don't escape the quotes...

Answer (score 1):

try it this way

```
element = browser.find_element(:xpath => "//*[@id=\"tabpage_1\"]/a")
```

**Note: Escape the double quotes.**

Tip - If you use a nice text editor (example - Sublime), the colour of the text will change and will help uou detect errors like these

Comment: You can even see the problem in the StackOverflow syntax highlighting ;)